# QML variable value get zeroed while changing the page

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I am using stackView and with a button press I chance the page by using `push` and `pop`. I want to save same variable value and when I open the page again, I want to keep continue using that variable with its value when page is closed.That is why I declared the variables in the main qml :

```
Window{
     id:main
     property var isSomethingOn:false
     StackView{
        id:contentFrame
        initialItem:Qt.resolvedUrl("qrc:/MainPage.qml")
        Connections{
           target:contentFrame.currentItem
           onBackButtonPressed:{
              contentFrame.pop()
              }}}}}
```

and in the other page I use that variable like:

```
Item{
   id:Page1
   signal backButtonPressed()
   Image{
      id:button1
      MultiPointTouchArea{
         main.isSomethingOn = !main.isSomethingOn
         if(main.isSomethingOn){
            button2.buttonImageColor="Imgs/button_left_red.png"
         }
         else{
            button2.buttonImageColor="Imgs/button_left_blue.png"
         }
      }
}
```

Now I expect `isSomethignOn` to be saved and not to be deleted between page transitions. But it indeed get deleted. How can I solve that issue?

Comment: how do you use that `isSomethingOn` variable? I guess the problem might be there, because your assumption that variable in main shouldn't change is correct

Comment: As a side note, don't use `var` properties unless they actually need to be `var`. For one thing, `var` properties don't automatically notify when their value changes. In your case, make it a `bool` instead.

Comment: @Amfasis I added that part to the code. Well that's not totally what I'll do but for now, I change the button color according to it. And yes, if the page gets destroyed during pop and re-created again with push( Which was saying the opposite in the docs), if I left button at red and re-opened the page again it might be blue. But in that case, to make it red again, that would take 2 presses. But it gets red again in the first press.

Comment: @JarMan Yes that solved that saving issue. Now if I leave the page when button is red and reopen it again. It start with blue color and it takes 2 presses to make it red again. But that arises another question. Why page gets destroyed and recrated with push and pop commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is getting saved, but you probably can't tell because bindings don't automatically work with `var` properties. `var` properties do not automatically notify when their value changes. You can manually trigger them by calling `isSomethingOnChanged()`, but there's no reason to do that unless you actually need your property to be a `var`. In your case changing it to a `bool` should be all you need to do.

For your additional question about `push` and `pop`, see the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-stackview.html#item-ownership). Particularly this line:

> This means that any item pushed onto a StackView will never be
> destroyed by the StackView; only items that StackView creates from
> Components or URLs are destroyed by the StackView.